# Clash between latexdiff and endfloat

Tags: latexdiff, endfloat

When I posted the original question I hadn't yet found the origin of the clash, which turned to be caused by `\endfloat`.

**Original question**

I just started to use `latexdiff` since I realized it could work well for something I was trying to do manually, i.e. underlining the new parts of a new version of a tex file.

I tried it with the default parameters and it worked quite OK (I just had a problem due to the presence of a `\SIrange` command with only two parameters, which, apparently, caused some trouble).

I then tried to change the markupstyle, and it worked only using `CFONT` (other than the default one). Since I am interested in `BOLD`, I'm trying to find out a way to overcome this problem.

The error says something like

```
! Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles. 
\clearpage ...rite \m@ne {}\vbox {}\penalty \\@Mi

l.104 \efloatseparator
```

The added commands from the preamble of working version are these

```
\providecommand{\DIFaddtex}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdeltex}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}   %DIF PREAMBLE
```

while those of the non-working version are these

```
\providecommand{\DIFaddtex}[1]{{\bf #1}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdeltex}[1]{} %DIF PREAMBLE
```

All the rest is the same. The `\DIFdeltex` (or the derived commands) might include citations, acronyms, references etc, and I suspect that one of these bad boys is causing the trouble.

Any idea of how to make the `BOLD`-based solution working?

**Edited question**

I think I found what the problem is. While stripping parts of code to post the MWE I realized that the problem occurred when, in the new version of my document, a figure was being removed.
And such problem is related, for some reason, to the usage of `endfloat`.

Given the following MWE for my **old** versions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Move figures to the end
%\usepackage{endfloat}

% Acronyms
\newacronym{MNA}{MNA}{my nice acronym}
% ------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\label{sec:mysec}
As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things). This is nonsense.
The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give \cref{fig:myfig} rise to the architectonic of practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would \SIrange{0}{1}{}.
%
\begin{align}
    A(\omega) = J(\omega) + 1
\end{align}
%
%
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \caption{Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of
    the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time.}
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
%
My final comment
\end{document}
```

and the following MWE for my **new** version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Move figures to the end
%\usepackage{endfloat}

% Acronyms
\newacronym{MNA}{MNA}{my nice acronym}
% ------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\label{sec:mysec}
As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things \cref{sec:mysec}).
The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give rise to the architectonic of practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section \ac{MNA}, reason would not be enough \citep{latexcompanion} \SIrange{0}{2}{}.
%
\begin{align}
    A(\omega) = J(\omega) + 2
\end{align}
%
My final comment
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Gossens et~al., 1993]{latexcompanion}
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin.
\newblock The \LaTeX\ Companion.
\newblock {Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts}, 1993.
\end{thebibliography}
%
\end{document}
```

when running

```
latexdiff -t BOLD old.tex new.tex > diff.tex
```

the `endfloat` screws up how `latexdiff` handles the new missing figure;
this is the snippet of code **without** the `endfloat` package (the `figure` environment is effectively removed)

```
%DIF <
\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < \begin{figure}[t]
%DIFDELCMD <     \centering
%DIFDELCMD <     %%%
%DIFDELCMD < \caption{%
{%DIFAUXCMD
\DIFdelFL{Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of
    the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time.}}
    %DIFAUXCMD
%DIFDELCMD < \label{fig:myfig}
%DIFDELCMD < \end{figure}
%DIFDELCMD < %%%
%DIF <
```

while this is the snippet of code **with** the `endfloat` package (the `figure` environment is NOT removed)

```
%DIF <
\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD <
\begin{figure}
[t]
%DIFDELCMD <     \centering
%DIFDELCMD <     %%%
%DIFDELCMD < \caption{%
{%DIFAUXCMD
\DIFdelFL{Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of
    the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time.}}
    %DIFAUXCMD
%DIFDELCMD < \label{fig:myfig}
%DIFDELCMD <
\end{figure}
%DIFDELCMD < %%%
%DIF <
```

An additional problem was given by the fact that if I used `\SIrange{0}{1}`, i.e. without the 3rd argument, instead of `\SIrange{0}{1}{}` the compilation would also exit with an error.

I don't know how helpful this can be, but I wanted to share to those who might encounter similar problems.
Cheers

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Otherwise that would be just guesswork. You could have at least posted the line/paragraph (with context) where that error occurs, with the exact error message (not "error says something like").

Comment: @gbernardi  My answer is really answering the question posed in your answer rather than the original question so you should probably completely edit your question and question title

Comment: I edited the title and included my edited question. However, I didn't remove the edited answer from the answer lists, since there are some comments I didn't want to lose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with endfloat is a bug affecting current and older versions of latexdiff (1.2.0 and older).

You have to patch two lines in the latexdiff script in function postprocess():

```
       # eliminate whitespace before and after
       s/^(\s*)(\\(?:begin|end)\{(?:figure|table)\})(\s*)$/$2/mg;
       # split lines with remaining characters before float enviroment commmand
-      s/^(.+)(\\(?:begin|end)\{(?:figure|table)\})/$1\n$2/mg;
+      s/^([^%]+)(\\(?:begin|end)\{(?:figure|table)\})/$1\n$2/mg;
       # split lines with remaining characters after float enviroment conmmand
-      s/(\\(?:begin|end)\{(?:figure|table)\})(.+)$/$1\n$2/mg;
+      s/^((?:[^%]+)\\(?:begin|end)\{(?:figure|table)\}(?:\[[a-zA-Z]+\])?)(.+)((?:%.*)?)$/$1\n$2$3/mg;
     }
```

Alternatively, get the latest version from latexdiff github site, or wait for the next release (note that github version deals with some pathological cases of escaped % signs that patch does not)

Comment: I tried the patch and it works, but it leaves a `[t]` from the figure in the `old.tex`. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Oops. I overlooked that. I have edited the patch and it should now be working.

Comment: I found two additional problems:
1) if the label of a figure is changed, and `endfloat` is used, we get something like
 \DIFdelbeginFL %DIFDELCMD < \label{fig:old_label}
 %DIFDELCMD < %%%
 \DIFdelendFL \DIFaddbeginFL \label{fig:new_label}
 \DIFaddendFL

which causes also the following paragraph after the figure to be placed at the end, with the other floats.

2) If the text from two paragraphs (having a newline command between them) is merged into a single paragraph, the new single paragraph will still retain the newline.

Comment: Hi, for new bug reports the comment section is not the righ place. Please use the interface at the latexdiff site on github: https://github.com/ftilmann/latexdiff .  Also when replying to a comment it is best to use @frederik designation. Otherwise I will not be notified and might easily overlook comments (I have been checking into stack exchange frequently the last few days but this is not always the case)

Comment: On the specific problem report: 1) The snippet looks just like latexdiff is doing its job as supposed to, so I am not sure why endfloat moves the following paragraph to the end. A full MWE would be required to assess this.

Comment: On 2) Hard to deal with that. If the deleted newline is between two deleted paragraphs you would want to retain it, so the behaviour would have to differ by context.  If you use option -t CCHANGEBAR, then at least you should be shown that something has changed (but this is less robust and might cause problems with some packages). I think this behaviour of showing deleted newlines is the same as used by Word.

Comment: Hi @frederik, you're right. I will simply post them on the github page. I will try to get a working MWE for 1) and, alas, 2) might just be an unfortunate situation that one has to solve manually ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what the problem is. While stripping parts of code to post the MWE I realized that the problem occurred when, in the new version of my document, a figure was being removed.
And such problem is related, for some reason, to the usage of `endfloat`.

Given the following MWE for my **old** versions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Move figures to the end
%\usepackage{endfloat}

% Acronyms
\newacronym{MNA}{MNA}{my nice acronym}
% ------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\label{sec:mysec}
As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things). This is nonsense.
The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give \cref{fig:myfig} rise to the architectonic of practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would \SIrange{0}{1}{}.
%
\begin{align}
    A(\omega) = J(\omega) + 1
\end{align}
%
%
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \caption{Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of
    the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time.}
    \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
%
My final comment
\end{document}
```

and the following MWE for my **new** version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Move figures to the end
%\usepackage{endfloat}

% Acronyms
\newacronym{MNA}{MNA}{my nice acronym}
% ------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\label{sec:mysec}
As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things \cref{sec:mysec}).
The paralogisms of practical reason are what first give rise to the architectonic of practical reason. As will easily be shown in the next section \ac{MNA}, reason would not be enough \citep{latexcompanion} \SIrange{0}{2}{}.
%
\begin{align}
    A(\omega) = J(\omega) + 2
\end{align}
%
My final comment
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[Gossens et~al., 1993]{latexcompanion}
Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach, and Alexander Samarin.
\newblock The \LaTeX\ Companion.
\newblock {Addison-Wesley, Reading, Massachusetts}, 1993.
\end{thebibliography}
%
\end{document}
```

when running

```
latexdiff -t BOLD old.tex new.tex > diff.tex
```

the `endfloat` screws up how `latexdiff` handles the new missing figure;
this is the snippet of code **without** the `endfloat` package (the `figure` environment is effectively removed)

```
%DIF <
\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < \begin{figure}[t]
%DIFDELCMD <     \centering
%DIFDELCMD <     %%%
%DIFDELCMD < \caption{%
{%DIFAUXCMD
\DIFdelFL{Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of
    the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time.}}
    %DIFAUXCMD
%DIFDELCMD < \label{fig:myfig}
%DIFDELCMD < \end{figure}
%DIFDELCMD < %%%
%DIF <
```

while this is the snippet of code **with** the `endfloat` package (the `figure` environment is NOT removed)

```
%DIF <
\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD <
\begin{figure}
[t]
%DIFDELCMD <     \centering
%DIFDELCMD <     %%%
%DIFDELCMD < \caption{%
{%DIFAUXCMD
\DIFdelFL{Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of
    the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time.}}
    %DIFAUXCMD
%DIFDELCMD < \label{fig:myfig}
%DIFDELCMD <
\end{figure}
%DIFDELCMD < %%%
%DIF <
```

An additional problem was given by the fact that if I used `\SIrange{0}{1}`, i.e. without the 3rd argument, instead of `\SIrange{0}{1}{}` the compilation would also exit with an error.

I don't know how helpful this can be, but I wanted to share to those who might encounter similar problems.
Cheers

Comment: Hi I cannot reproduce this with latexdiff v1.2.0.  It runs fine with both BOLD and default markup style. Which version are you using? SIUnitx support was introduced in 1.1.0

Comment: Hi. Thanks for trying. Did you try both the versions with and without the `endfloat` package?

Comment: You are right I did not spot that you had actually commented out the `endfloat` package. So you found an actual bug - fix is on the way. Also, the `SIUnitx` command was not in your MWE, so I haven't actually tested that.

Comment: Good for the `endfloat`.
Regarding the comment on `siunitx`, it is indeed contained in both the MWEs: there's a `\SIrange`command right before the equation.
However, the command is already called using the "workaround", i.e. by passing an empty third argument. If you remove the last `{}`, you will see that it doesn't work.

Comment: OK. Today I won't have any more time to look into this, though.

Comment: According to the manual \SIrange always has three arguments. If you don't have the final `{}`, then the following `.` is interpreted as its third argument.  This breaks the latexdiff rule, that arguments must always be surrounded by curly braces (see manual). Relaxing this requirement would mean latexdiff would have to know how many arguments each and every command has - such a database does not exist to my knowledge and would be extremely challenging to compile, given the number of packages out there. So the final `{}` is required by SIunitx alone, if you want to have a clean input.

Comment: I see; I think I initially decided to use `\SIrange` in that case because I wanted to keep the style of other intervals, but it would have probably been better to use `\numrange`in this case. Thanks for the explanation.